# javascript regexp both character is optional but merely one is invalid

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string for checking regular expression in javascript. The string can contain `+8` or only `8` or can be an empty string. But it cannot contain merely a `+` sign.

**These are valid:** `+8` or `8` or  ( 3rd one indicates empty string)

**This is invalid:** `+`

The code I have tried:

```
var x=/^\+?(8)?$/.test("+8")? 'ok':'not';
document.write(x);
```

Everything is ok with this code. Problem is that, this code returns true if the string contains `only a + sign`, which should be false. How to implement as I have wanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
^(\+?8)?$
```

Testing it -

```
> /^(\+?8)?$/.test("+")? 'ok':'not';
"not"
> /^(\+?8)?$/.test("+8")? 'ok':'not';
"ok"
> /^(\+?8)?$/.test("")? 'ok':'not';
"ok"
```

Comment: Very good one. It seems the optional groups perform better than alternation with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:\+?8|)$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/25

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other answers, but more explicit:

```
/^(?:\+8|8|)$/.test("8")
```

Explained:

```
^       - Begining of the string
(?:     - open non capturing group, used to be able to OR (|)
\+8|8|  - either "+8" or "8" or ""
)       - close the group
$       - end of string
```

The `(\+8|8|)` means: "either '+8', or '8' or '' (empty string)".

The `(?:` - non capturing group - is used to group conditions separated by logical OR (`|`) but making it clear that intention is not the value of the group itself, but merely to use `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Use following `regex`:

```
/(\+8|8)/
```

This will allow only one of the group to be valid.

Comment: There is no space, that was supposed to be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:
`((\+)?8)?`